# What is the difference between authorization code and Client Credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am new to Oauth, can anyone explain what is the difference between Authorization code and client credentials grant type  in Oauth

And also in which we need to use these two 
I really appreciate the answers

Answer (score 8):

The **authorization code** is obtained by using an authorization server as an intermediary between the
client and resource owner. Instead of requesting authorization directly from the resource owner, the
client directs the resource owner to an authorization server (via its user-agent), which in turn directs the
resource owner back to the client with the authorization code.

Before directing the resource owner back to the client with the authorization code, the authorization
server authenticates the resource owner and obtains authorization. Because the resource owner only
authenticates with the authorization server, the resource owner’s credentials are never shared with
the client.

The authorization code provides a few important security benefits, such as the ability to authenticate
the client, as well as the transmission of the access token directly to the client without passing it through
the resource owner’s user-agent and potentially exposing it to others, including the resource owner.

**Client credentials** are used as an authorization grant typically when the client is acting on its own behalf
(the client is also the resource owner) or is requesting access to protected resources based on an
authorization previously arranged with the authorization server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Even it's 4 years old answer, the "Client is also the resource owner" was a light bulb moment to my research towards OAuth 2.0 and beyond, thanks man !